# Difference between "." and "./" and "./." for path

Tags: python, linux, terminal, git-bash

I tried ls '.', ls './', and ls './.' , and they all give me the same results.

But for a certain file, I can only run it with "python file ./" and not the other two options. So I wonder what is the difference between them.

edit:

I did not write this.

```
try:
    in_dir = sys.argv[1]
except:
    sys.exit("Usage: python formatter_oocl.py path/to/dir")

in_dir = "OOCL_RAW_DATA/" # name of directory where xls files will be read from
files = os.listdir("./"+in_dir)
#files = ['./' + in_dir + files[i] for i in range(len(files))]
print(files)
```

Thank you

Comment: The difference is in your program which we do not have access to.

Comment: A wild guess would be that your program assumes that it can take the path argument and concatenate a filename onto it directly. This works only if the path argument is empty or ends with `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` is your current folder. The `/` afterwards only specifies that it is a folder and allows you to specify other folders/files afterwards *(eg. `myfolder/myfile`)*
so
`./.` is `current directory/current directory`

As far as I know, there is no difference...

`./yourfile` executes your file (if that is what you were asking)

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided samples of the solution in the context of the original question - this will also make it easier for others to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`., ./ and ./.` all refer to the current directory.  You use `./file.ext` to run an executable file.